# How to do preDispatch forwarding in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, dispatcher, forwarding

I want to use `_forward()` in `preDispatch` after checking if the user is logged in in every controller.

The scenario is quite easy: If the user is not logged in, it should be forwarded to `loginAction` either in the same controller or in another controller.

This would cause an infinite loop, as the dispatch process starts over again, calling `preDispatch` again and the forwarding would start everything again.

The only solution I was able to come up with was to check if the `loginAction` is already set in the request.

So my question is, how would the sophisticated developer handle this issue?

**UPDATE**
Just after hitting the send button, the ghost of the holy awareness came across ;)
Another idea would be to build a `LoginController` to handle the login request. Or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a combination of a Zend_Controller_Plugin and an AuthController to protect my sites. It supports password resets, forced password changes, and automatic account locking, hence the moderate complexity.

Note that I use Doctrine, so this obviously can't just be cut and pasted into your application, but it should function with minimal changes. I removed a few methods specific to my application, but all the general authentication foo is there.

**Plugin**

```
<?php
class Hobo_Controller_Plugin_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            if ('logout' != $request->getActionName()) {
                if (! $request->getParam('force_password_change')
                    && $this->_checkPasswordExpiry($auth->getIdentity()->username)
                ) {
                    $request->setParam('force_password_change', true);
                    $request->setModuleName('default')
                        ->setControllerName('auth')
                        ->setActionName('change-password');
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Defer more complex authentication logic to AuthController
            if ('auth' != $this->getRequest()->getControllerName()) {
                $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
                $redirector->gotoSimple('restricted', 'auth');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _checkPasswordExpiry($username)
    {
        // Look up user and return true if password is expired
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

```
<?php

class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        $this->_errorMessenger = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger();
        $this->_errorMessenger->setActionController($this)->init();
        $this->_errorMessenger->setNamespace('error');

        $this->_noticeMessenger = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger();
        $this->_noticeMessenger->setActionController($this)->init();
        $this->_noticeMessenger->setNamespace('notice');

        $this->view->errors = $this->_errorMessenger->getMessages();
        $this->view->notices = $this->_noticeMessenger->getMessages();
    }

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        if (! $this->_auth->hasIdentity()) {
            if (! in_array($this->_request->getActionName(), array(
                    'logout', 'identify', 'forgot-password', 'reset-password', 'restricted'))
                ) {
                $this->_redirect('/auth/restricted');
            }
        }
    }

    public function restrictedAction()
    {
        // Shows access restricted page
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        $this->_auth->clearIdentity();
        Zend_Session::destroy();
        $this->_redirect('/');
    }

    public function identifyAction()
    {
        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $username = $this->_getParam('username');
            $password = $this->_getParam('password');

            if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
                $this->_flashError('Username or password cannot be blank.');
            } else {
                $user = new dUser();
                $result = $user->login($username, $password);

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    $user->fromArray((array) $this->_auth->getIdentity());

                    if ($this->_getParam('changepass') || $user->is_password_expired) {
                        $this->_redirect('auth/change-password');
                        return;
                    }
                    $this->_doRedirect($user);
                    return;
                } else {
                    $this->_doFailure($result->getIdentity());
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('/');
    }

    public function changePasswordAction()
    {
        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $username = $this->_auth->getIdentity()->username;
            $formData = $this->_request->getParams();

            if (empty($formData['password'])
                || empty($formData['new_password'])
                || empty($formData['confirm_password'])
            ) {
                $this->_flashError('Password cannot be blank.');
                $this->_redirect('auth/change-password');
            } elseif ($formData['new_password'] !== $formData['confirm_password']) {
                $this->_flashError('Password and confirmation do not match.');
                $this->_redirect('auth/change-password');
            } else {
                $user = new dUser();
                $result = $user->login($username, $formData['password']);

                if ($result->isValid()) {

                    $user->updatePassword($username, $formData['new_password']);
                    $this->_flashNotice('Password updated successfully!');
                    $this->_redirect('/');
                } else {
                    $this->_flashError('Invalid username or password!');
                    $this->_redirect('auth/change-password');
                }
            }

        }

        if ($this->_getParam('force_password_change')) {
            $this->view->notice = 'Your password has expired. You must change your password to continue.';
        }
    }

    public function forgotPasswordAction()
    {
        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            // Pseudo-random uppercase 6 digit hex value
            $resetCode = strtoupper(substr(sha1(uniqid(rand(),true)),0,6));

            Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->update('dUser u')
                ->set('u.reset_code', '?', array($resetCode))
                ->where('u.username = ?', array($this->_getParam('username')))
                ->execute();

            $this->_doMail($this->_getParam('username'), $resetCode);

            $this->_flashNotice("Password reset request received.");
            $this->_flashNotice("An email with further instructions, including your <em>Reset Code</em>, has been sent to {$this->_getParam('username')}.");
            $this->_redirect("auth/reset-password/username/{$this->_getParam('username')}");
        }
    }

    public function resetPasswordAction()
    {
        $this->view->username = $this->_getParam('username');
        $this->view->reset_code = $this->_getParam('reset_code');

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->_request->getParams();
            if (empty($formData['username']) || empty($formData['reset_code'])) {
                $this->_flashError('Username or reset code cannot be blank.');
                $this->_redirect('auth/reset-password');
            } elseif ($formData['new_password'] !== $formData['confirm_password']) {
                $this->_flashError('Password and confirmation do not match.');
                $this->_redirect('auth/reset-password');
            } else {
                $user = new dUser();
                $result = $user->loginWithResetCode($formData['username'], $formData['reset_code']);

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    $user->updatePassword($result->getIdentity(), $formData['new_password']);

                    $user->fromArray((array) $this->_auth->getIdentity());

                    $this->_flashNotice('Password updated successfully!');
                    $this->_doRedirect($user);
                } else {
                    $this->_doFailure($result->getIdentity());
                    $this->_redirect('auth/reset-password');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _doRedirect($user)
    {
        $this->_helper->Redirector->gotoUserDefault($user);
    }

    protected function _flashError($message)
    {
        $this->_errorMessenger->addMessage($message);
    }

    protected function _flashNotice($message)
    {
        $this->_noticeMessenger->addMessage($message);
    }

    protected function _doFailure($username)
    {
        $user = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('dUser u')
            ->select('u.is_locked')
            ->where('u.username = ?', array($username))
            ->fetchOne();

        if ($user->is_locked) {
            $this->_flashError('This account has been locked.');
        } else {
            $this->_flashError('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Great example, how to set up things quickly and reasonable.

Comment: Great job, $this->_redirect(); didnt worked only works yours.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use the following:

```
  $request->setParam('skippredispatch',true);
  $this->_forward('index');
```

In your controller and then [before] this

```
// If overwriting jump the pre-dispatchy bits
if ($request->getParam('skippredispatch')){
  $request->setParam('skippredispatch',null);
  return;
}
```

Effectively skipping the predispatch loop which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This process could be in any action, but why not loginAction, or indexAction in LoginController?

1. Check for a logged in identity: found? redirect to index
2. Check for post params: found? validate, set identity or set error messages
3. Print form

Edit: might've been too tired to realize the real problem. I'd start out with something like a protected/private member in each login-protected controller, such as `protected $authNeeded = true;`, and check for it in `Zend_Controller_Action::init()`. This could lead to repeated code, so another option would be to just perform this code in `AuthNeededController` which all login-protected controller extends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm gonna use this design that has been proposed as well by hobodave. His answer goes more into details, so he gets the tick.